# Self sizing UITableView cell not sizing correctly

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode8

I have a `UITableView` with Static cells.  The description label should present many lines of text but only presents one.

I have selected the description label and set number of lines to 0.  I've also set it to Word Wrap.

I've set Automatic Dimension as follows:

```
class BeerTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var beerName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var brewer: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var beerDescription: UILabel!

    var scannedBeer: Beer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44

        beerName.text = scannedBeer.name
        brewer.text = scannedBeer.brewer
        beerDescription.text = scannedBeer.description
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

I've pinned the label to the top and bottom of the ContentView as follows:
[image: AutoLayout]

[image: Number of lines]

Comment: Give height constrain as Greater then equal to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `heightForRowAt indexPath:` and `estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath:` of `UITableViewDelegate`, return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

Just set table view `delegate` as `self` and use the following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't as I'm using static cells, not dynamic.

Comment: You can use, no matter you're using static cells or dynamic cells.

Comment: heightForRowAtIndexPath worked!  Thanks very much.  Can you please edit your answer... The first function should be heightForRow.  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your **beereDescription** label nil on ViewDidLoad . you need to assign value on cellForRowAtIndexpath instead of ViewDidLoad.

And you can't connect IBOutlet of cell's subview in UIViewcontroller class.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let identifier = "cellIdentifier"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier)

        beerDescription: UILabel? = (newsCell?.viewWithTag(101) as? UILabel) // assign tag to label in cell
        beerDescription.text = scannedBeer.description
       return cell

}
```